# Error On running the command docker-compose up in Macbook(Apple M1 Pro)

Tags: docker, macos, intellij-idea

I am running the command `docker-compose up --scale service-promotions=0` to run my project in IntelliJ but I am getting this error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:6.5.1-jdk11                                                                                       2.7s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:6.5.1-jdk11:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:449a6385fa079f420cd7cd4ce34601740e046dfdcaaaf272d6cc5313104859df: not found
```

I am using 11.0.13 2021-10-19 LTS version of java. Is there anyone here who can help me in solving this error as I have never worked with docker before.

I have checked the docker-compose.yml file also there value is dockerfile: Dockerfile. I tried with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`command also but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This error can be solved by adding this line in docker-compose.yml file `platform: linux/amd64`. It worked for me